# How Do I Insert A Bash Variable Into A Value on InfluxDB?

Tags: bash, influxdb, influxql

I am trying to do the following:

```
influx -database 'polls' -execute 'insert nodeMemory,NodeID=1,server=server01 values="$nodemem1"']
```

I get the following errors:

```
ERR: {"error":"unable to parse 'nodeMemory,NodeID=1,server=server01 values=`$nodemem1`': invalid boolean"}
```

How do I enter a variable as a value?

I expected it to enter the variable

Comment: Note that from a security perspective, this is a Very Bad Idea; "real" languages have database client libraries that provide mechanisms to separate code and data; bash doesn't have such a facility. (Not that it isn't possible to write database clients that permit unambiguously correct use from bash -- I've _written_ such a client in the past, but it was proprietary to an old employer and for a different database, and also not itself written in native shell, so that's neither here nor there in the present).

Answer (score 1):

You have the query wrapped in single quotes `'` instead of double quotes.  Try double-quoting, and escape the inner double quotes:

```
... -execute "insert nodeMemory,NodeID=1,server=server01 values=\"$nodemem1\""
```

Depending on what influxdb expects, you might even be able to do away with the inner double quotes altogether:

```
... -execute "insert nodeMemory,NodeID=1,server=server01 values=$nodemem1"
```

Comment: One can also end the single quotes then begin double quotes; `'single-quoted-part'-unquoted-part-"double-quoted-part"` is all one string (which contains no literal quotes at all).

Comment: First example does the following insert:

time                NodeID server     values
----                ------ ------     ------
1698771139033138109 1      server0101 1921024000"

Second example:

ERR: {"error":"unable to parse 'nodeMemory,NodeID=1,server=server01 values=1921024000]': invalid number"}

Comment: I can't get the value to insert correctly

Comment: what are the data types for each column?

Comment: it also seems like you have a column called `values` -- that's a SQL keyword, and there's risk (not necessarily in this exact scenario) for confusion

Comment: and maybe the square bracket needs to be omitted? I see a square bracket in this `...values=1921024000]': invalid number"...`

Comment: Values is coming up as a string but I need it to be a float

Comment: This is driving me nuts. I'm basically trying to move from MySQL to InfluxDB. I need this to insert a float:

influx -database sbdpolls -execute "insert nodeMemory,NodeID=1,host=server01 values::=\$nodemem1\"

When I press enter it goes to >